# Refresh GridView to an other WebForm

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview on "Webform1.aspx" ,i want when i click the refresh button on "webform2.aspx","webform1.aspx" refresh or better way "webform1.aspx" gridview just refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that from webform1 opened the webform2, try:

**webform2.aspx** From here you can refresh the webform1.asp or you can call a function.

```
<script>
function refresh_webform1(){
    window.opener.location.reload();
}

function CallFunctionFrom_webform1(){
    //example function display_ct();
    window.opener.display_ct();
}

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="refresh_webform1()" value="Refresh webform 1">
<input type="button" onclick="CallFunctionFrom_webform1()" value="Call Function From Webform1">
```

**webform1.aspx**

```
<script>
function openWebform2(){
    window.open("webform2.aspx","windowName", "width=200,height=200,scrollbars=no");
    //or 
    //window.open("webform2.aspx","_blank" );
}

//example function display_ct();
function display_ct() {
    var x = new Date();
    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

<span id='ct' ></span>
<input type="button" onclick="openWebform2()" value="Open WebForm 2">
```